# How to modify a variable in a file

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have a config file like this:

```
# Default LIST="nil"
LIST="element1 element2 element3"
```

What would be the simplest way to modify LIST from a shell script?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you have in mind? What's the goal and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I believe the rest of the details would convolute the question.

Comment: @AlbertoSalviaNovella I believe you should state what you are after. If you have multiple strings in a variable you probably want an array variable like  `list=( element1 element2 element3 )`

Comment: The variable I want to modify is already defined as a single string, but thanks for the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/LIST\=.*/LIST="element4 element5"/' config_file
```

If you only want LIST to be updated if it's not commented, add `^` (start of line):

```
sed -i 's/^LIST\=.*/LIST="element4 element5"/' config_file
```

Comment: I detected an issue. If LIST is in COMMENT, it will also be changed there.

Comment: Thats not a bug, it's a feature ;-) See my update.

Comment: Now it works nicely :P

Answer (score 2):

Same answer as the accepted one, but ready to use in a **script**. In case someone finds it useful:

```
#! /bin/bash
#  (GPL3+) Alberto Salvia Novella (es20490446e)


modifyVariableInFile () {
    variable="${1}"
    content="${2}"
    file="${3}"

    if [ ! -f "${file}" ]; then
        echo "modifyVariableInFile: file doesn't exist: ${file}"
        exit 1
    fi

    sed -i "s/^${variable}\=.*/${variable}=\"${content}\"/" "${file}"
}


modifyVariableInFile ${@}
```